# while loop jtextfield accepts only letters

Tags: java, while-loop, jtextfield

I want to force a textfield to only accept letters and white space.
I tried this function that looks fine to me but it only prints:

accepted and i=0 So I can see that it's a problem of local variable or smthg like that;

```
public void ff()
{Boolean bool=true;
int i=0;


     name=textField.getText();
     while(bool && i<name.length())
     {
         if(Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
             i++;
         else
            bool=false;
     }
    if (bool=true) 
            System.out.println("accepted"+i);
    else 
            System.out.println("wrong"+i);

}
```

Can you help me to figure it out? and Please I want to use this function not documentfilter or formattedtext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bool=true` is assignment, not comparison.

Change `if (bool=true)` to `if (bool==true)` or `if (bool)`. Otherwise, you'll always print `accepted`.

Comment: Ahh that's right. my eyes are letting me down. thanks